# Windows Batch - Find word in one string matching word in another string and capture output

Tags: windows, batch-file

While this may seem easy to some, I've struggled for hours on it.

I have a file:

```
MYFOLDER,JobE,JobD_ENDED_OK,
MYFOLDER,JobD,JobC_ENDED_OK,JobD_ENDED_OK
MYFOLDER,JobD,JobB_ENDED_OK,
MYFOLDER,JobC,JobA_ENDED_OK,JobC_ENDED_OK
MYFOLDER,JobB,JobA_ENDED_OK,JobB_ENDED_OK
MYFOLDER,JobA,,JobA_ENDED_OK
```

I need to loop through and find where token 4 in one line matches token 3 in another line and then echo a statement to a file. I am looking for an output file that shows this:

```
MYFOLDER_JobA_MYFOLDER_JobB matches JobA_ENDED_OK
MYFOLDER_JobA_MYFOLDER_JobC matches JobA_ENDED_OK
MYFOLDER_JobB_MYFOLDER_JobD matches JobB_ENDED_OK
MYFOLDER_JobC_MYFOLDER_JobD matches JobC_ENDED_OK
MYFOLDER_JobD_MYFOLDER_JobE matches JobD_ENDED_OK
```

I know it's a FOR loop with a DO, I am just not getting the rest of it.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code as well - someone may be able to spot where you have gone wrong

Comment: Please show your attempt. Please also show *how* your desired output matches the input data. For instance, your output shows "JobE" but there's no mention of "JobE" in your input data.

Comment: @Magoo

3 parameter in Line 1 matches the 4 parameter in Line 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q46510665.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%h IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "col4line=%%h"
 SET "col4line=!col4line:,=|,|!"
 FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims=," %%a IN ("!col4line!") DO IF "%%d" neq "|" (
  FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%H IN ("%filename1%") DO (
   SET "col3line=%%H"
   SET "col3line=!col3line:,=|,|!"
   FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims=," %%A IN ("!col3line!") DO (
    IF "%%d|"=="%%C" (
     SET "reportline=%%a_%%b_%%A_%%B matches %%C"
     ECHO !reportline:^|=!
    )
   )
  ) 
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q46510665.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

For each line in the file, set a variable `col4line` to the entire line via `%%h`, then replace each `,` with `|,|` so that successive `,` will be separated. Tokenise on `,` and ignore any line which has simply `|` as its 4th token (ie last-column-empty).

Repeat the process for every line in the file this time through `%%H` into `col3line` (note case differential to use different actual metavariables) and if the third column matches the fourth column+`|` from the outer loop, assemble the report line from the tokens and output, removing the `|`s.

Comment: Thanks @Magoo.   I got lost in how many FOR loops were required, I was trying with two and not using SET to do it. 

Much appreciated!!